# JPopupMenu Modality

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jpopupmenu, modality

I'm not entirely sure if "modality" is the correct term that I need to describe the issue, but I have a standalone application with a JDialog. The JDialog is set to block all other parts of the application until the dialog is closed. I recently started adding a sort of auto-suggestion feature using a JPopupMenu. This worked fine in the rest of the application, but when trying it as part of the dialog, I can't seem to click on the popup which I'm assuming is because of the modal exclusion type of the dialog. Does anyone know a hack to get around this?

Code used to start the JDialog:

```
NewPlayerDialog dialog = new NewPlayerDialog();
dialog.setLocation(Main.getWindow().getLocation().x + Main.getWindow().getWidth()/2 - dialog.getWidth()/2, Main.getWindow().getLocation().y + Main.getWindow().getHeight()/2 - dialog.getHeight()/2);
dialog.setModalExclusionType(ModalExclusionType.APPLICATION_EXCLUDE);
dialog.setResizable(false);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Code within the JDialog:

```
package com.etan.bracketrunner2;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;

import com.etan.dbhs.DBHSDatabaseIntermediary;
import com.etan.dbhs.DBHSPlayerInitializer;
import com.etan.widgets.UnderlinedLabel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class NewPlayerDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

    private JTextField fnTextField;
    private JPopupMenu fnPopup;
    private ActionListener fnActionListener;
    private JTextField lnTextField;
    private JPopupMenu lnPopup;
    private ActionListener lnActionListener;
    private JTextField idTextField;
    private JTextField handicapTextField;

    private JButton okButton;
    private JButton cancelButton;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public NewPlayerDialog() {

        super(Main.getWindow(), "New Player", Dialog.ModalityType.TOOLKIT_MODAL);

        Font font = new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 14);

        JLabel fnLabel = new UnderlinedLabel("First Name");
        fnLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        fnLabel.setFont(font);
        JPanel fnLabelPanel = new JPanel();
        fnLabelPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        fnLabelPanel.add(fnLabel);

        JLabel lnLabel = new UnderlinedLabel("Last Name");
        lnLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lnLabel.setFont(font);
        JPanel lnLabelPanel = new JPanel();
        lnLabelPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        lnLabelPanel.add(lnLabel);

        JLabel idLabel = new UnderlinedLabel("ID#");
        idLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        idLabel.setFont(font);
        JPanel idLabelPanel = new JPanel();
        idLabelPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        idLabelPanel.add(idLabel);

        JLabel handicapLabel = new UnderlinedLabel("Handicap");
        handicapLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        handicapLabel.setFont(font);
        JPanel handicapLabelPanel = new JPanel();
        handicapLabelPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        handicapLabelPanel.add(handicapLabel);

        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
        labelPanel.add(fnLabelPanel);
        labelPanel.add(lnLabelPanel);
        labelPanel.add(idLabelPanel);
        labelPanel.add(handicapLabelPanel);

        fnTextField = new JTextField(7);
        fnTextField.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        fnTextField.setFont(font);

        fnPopup = new JPopupMenu();

        PopupMenuListener fnListener = new PopupMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {

                fnPopup.setLocation(fnTextField.getLocationOnScreen().x,
                        fnTextField.getLocationOnScreen().y + fnTextField.getHeight());
                fnPopup.setPopupSize(fnTextField.getWidth(), fnPopup.getComponentCount() * 20);

            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                ;
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                ;
            }

        };

        fnPopup.addPopupMenuListener(fnListener);

        fnTextField.setComponentPopupMenu(fnPopup);

        fnActionListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                fnTextField.setText(e.getActionCommand());
                fnPopup.setVisible(false);

            }// ends actionPerformed()

        };

        FocusListener fnFocusListener = new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

                resetFirstNamePopup();

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

                fnPopup.setVisible(false);

            }

        };

        KeyListener fnKeyListener = new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                ;

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                ;

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                resetFirstNamePopup();

            }

        };

        fnTextField.addActionListener(fnActionListener);
        fnTextField.addFocusListener(fnFocusListener);
        fnTextField.addKeyListener(fnKeyListener);

        lnTextField = new JTextField(7);
        lnTextField.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lnTextField.setFont(font);

        lnPopup = new JPopupMenu();

        PopupMenuListener lnListener = new PopupMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {

                lnPopup.setLocation(lnTextField.getLocationOnScreen().x,
                        lnTextField.getLocationOnScreen().y + lnTextField.getHeight());
                lnPopup.setPopupSize(lnTextField.getWidth(), lnPopup.getComponentCount() * 20);

            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                ;
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                ;
            }

        };

        lnPopup.addPopupMenuListener(lnListener);

        lnTextField.setComponentPopupMenu(lnPopup);

        lnActionListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                lnTextField.setText(e.getActionCommand());
                lnPopup.setVisible(false);

            }// ends actionPerformed()

        };

        FocusListener lnFocusListener = new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

                resetLastNamePopup();

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

                lnPopup.setVisible(false);

            }

        };

        KeyListener lnKeyListener = new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                ;

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                ;

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                resetLastNamePopup();

            }

        };

        lnTextField.addActionListener(lnActionListener);
        lnTextField.addFocusListener(lnFocusListener);
        lnTextField.addKeyListener(lnKeyListener);

        idTextField = new JTextField(3);
        idTextField.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        idTextField.setFont(font);

        handicapTextField = new JTextField(3);
        handicapTextField.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        handicapTextField.setFont(font);

        JPanel fnTextFieldPanel = new JPanel();
        fnTextFieldPanel.add(fnTextField);

        JPanel lnTextFieldPanel = new JPanel();
        lnTextFieldPanel.add(lnTextField);

        JPanel idTextFieldPanel = new JPanel();
        idTextFieldPanel.add(idTextField);

        JPanel handicapTextFieldPanel = new JPanel();
        handicapTextFieldPanel.add(handicapTextField);

        JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
        infoPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
        infoPanel.add(fnTextFieldPanel);
        infoPanel.add(lnTextFieldPanel);
        infoPanel.add(idTextFieldPanel);
        infoPanel.add(handicapTextFieldPanel);

        okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        okButton.setFont(font);
        okButton.addActionListener(this);

        cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        cancelButton.setFont(font);
        cancelButton.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 0, 0, 0, new Color(160, 0, 0)));
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        buttonPanel.add(okButton);
        buttonPanel.add(cancelButton);

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(160, 0, 0), 4));
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        content.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        setContentPane(content);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }// ends NewPlayerDialog()

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        if(evt.getSource().equals(okButton)) {

            if(checkInfo()) {
                DBHSPlayerInitializer init = new DBHSPlayerInitializer();
                int id = 0;
                float handicap = 0;
                try {
                    if(!idTextField.getText().equals("")) {
                        id = Integer.parseInt(idTextField.getText());
                    }
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    Main.getControlPanel().showErrorMessage(
                            "Please make sure that all inputs under ID# are integer numbers.");
                }

                try {
                    if(!handicapTextField.getText().equals("")) {
                        handicap = Float.parseFloat(handicapTextField.getText());
                    }
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    Main.getControlPanel().showErrorMessage(
                            "Please make sure that all inputs under handicap are number values.");
                }
                Player player;
                try {
                    player = init.initialize(fnTextField.getText(),
                            lnTextField.getText(), id, handicap, 0);
                    Main.getControlPanel().getScreen().getPlayers().addPlayer(player);
                    Main.getControlPanel().showPrizesDialog();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Main.getControlPanel().showErrorMessage("There was an error while trying to add the new player.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            dispose();
            Main.getControlPanel().updateInfo();

        } else if(evt.getSource().equals(cancelButton)) {

            dispose();

        }

    }// ends actionPerformed()

    boolean checkInfo() {

        String fn = fnTextField.getText();
        String ln = lnTextField.getText();
        String id = idTextField.getText();
        String handicap = handicapTextField.getText();

        if(id.equals("") && (fn.equals("") && ln.equals(""))) {
            Main.getControlPanel().showErrorMessage("Please make sure that all players have either their first and last names, or their id number filled in.");

            return false;
        }

        if(fn.equals("") && ln.equals("")) {
            try{
                Integer.parseInt(id);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                if(!fn.equals("") && !ln.equals("")) {
                    Main.getControlPanel().showErrorMessage("Please make sure that " + fn + " " + ln + "'s ID is an integer number.");
                } else {
                    Main.getControlPanel().showErrorMessage("Please make sure that each player's ID is an integer number.");
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        if(!handicap.equals("")) {
            try{
                Float.parseFloat(handicap);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                Main.getControlPanel().showErrorMessage("Please make sure that " + fn + " " + ln + "'s handicap is numeric.");

                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }// ends checkInfo()

    /**
     * Used for an anonymous ActionListener in the 
     * PlayerPanel.
     * 
     * @return cancelButton
     */
    JButton getCancelButton() {

        return cancelButton;

    }// ends getCancelButton()

    /**
     * Used for an anonymous ActionListener in the 
     * PlayerPanel.
     * 
     * @return okButton
     */
    JButton getOkButton() {

        return okButton;

    }// ends getOkButton()

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {

        ;

    }// ends mouseClicked()

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {

        if(evt.getComponent().getClass().getName().equals("javax.swing.JMenuItem")) {

            evt.getComponent().setBackground(new Color(120,145,170));

        }

    }// ends mouseEntered()

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {

        if(evt.getComponent().getClass().getName().equals("javax.swing.JMenuItem")) {

            evt.getComponent().setBackground(new Color(238,238,238));

        }

    }// ends mouseExited()

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {

        ;

    }// ends mousePressed()

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {

        ;

    }// ends mouseReleased()

    /**
     * Repopulates fnPopup if necessary.
     */
    private void resetFirstNamePopup() {

        fnPopup.setVisible(false);
        fnPopup.removeAll();

        if(!(fnTextField.getText().equals("") && lnTextField.getText().equals(""))) {

            JMenuItem item = null;
            String[] names = DBHSDatabaseIntermediary.getFirstNames(fnTextField.getText(), lnTextField.getText());
            for(int i=0; i < names.length; i++) {

                item = new JMenuItem(names[i]);
                item.addActionListener(fnActionListener);
                item.addMouseListener(NewPlayerDialog.this);
                fnPopup.add(item);

            }

            if(names.length > 0 && !names[0].equals("")) {
                fnPopup.setVisible(true);
            }
            fnPopup.grabFocus();

        }

    }// ends resetFirstNamePopup()

    /**
     * Repopulates lnPopup if necessary.
     */
    private void resetLastNamePopup() {

        lnPopup.setVisible(false);
        lnPopup.removeAll();

        if(!(fnTextField.getText().equals("") && lnTextField.getText().equals(""))) {

            JMenuItem item = null;
            String[] names = DBHSDatabaseIntermediary.getLastNames(fnTextField.getText(), lnTextField.getText());
            for(int i=0; i < names.length; i++) {

                item = new JMenuItem(names[i]);
                item.addActionListener(lnActionListener);
                item.addMouseListener(NewPlayerDialog.this);
                lnPopup.add(item);

            }

            if(names.length > 0 && !names[0].equals("")) {
                lnPopup.setVisible(true);
            }
            lnPopup.grabFocus();

        }

    }// ends resetLastNamePopup()

}// ends Class
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

I changed the modality type on the dialog to DOCUMENT_MODAL and everything worked correctly.